# React downgrading dependencies not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, react-dom

I created a react app on vscode (node) using create-react-app and the name.

When I downgraded the react & react-dom versions from 18 to 17.0.2 its giving me the following error:

Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0

Why is this giving me this error when I downgraded my dependencies? (I also deleted node modules and package lock-json).

When I put "npm i" this is the error i get:

npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm WARN     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^17.0.2" from the root project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

React Testing Library (`@testing-library/react`) v13 only supports React 18. If you want to use it with React 17, you need to downgrade `@testing-library/react` to version 12.

See https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1111